# How to fix the app event log warning MSDTC encountered an error (HR=0x80000171)

Tags: msdtc

I keep getting the following warning message in the application event log (Win2012R2):

> MSDTC encountered an error (HR=0x80000171) while attempting to
>   establish a secure connection with system

I have read all the related questions, and none of them helped resolve the issue.

The application on that server works as expected as far as i can tell, but i don`t like the warning showing up, and need help resolving it.

The warning happens once every few days, i can sometimes make it happen by restarting the MSDTC service.

I have configured the DTC for network enabled transactions according to [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753620(v=ws.10).aspx) MSDN article.

The config shows up as expected on DTC startup:

```
MSDTC started with the following settings:

 Security Configuration (OFF = 0 and ON = 1):
 Allow Remote Administrator = 0,
 Network Clients = 1,
 Transaction Manager Communication: 
 Allow Inbound Transactions = 1,
 Allow Outbound Transactions = 1,
 Transaction Internet Protocol (TIP) = 0,
  Enable XA Transactions = 1,
  Enable SNA LU 6.2 Transactions = 1,
  MSDTC Communications Security = Mutual Authentication Required,
 Account = NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService,
  Firewall Exclusion Detected = 0

 Transaction Bridge Installed = 0
 Filtering Duplicate Events = 1
```

I also turned on the MSDTC CM trace, as specified in the [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926099/how-to-enable-diagnostic-tracing-for-ms-dtc-on-a-windows-based-compute)

In the trace file i found the following errors, but could not find any information on how to resolve them, so here we are.

> 12-24-2017 14:18:46:354 : [ b9c. 2e8] 0x00000000 [    TRACE_CM] [ 
>   TRACE_INFO] InitRpcSecurity
>   (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrrpc.cpp@382): Calling
>   RpcServerRegisterAuthInfo with mrfappdvl$@DEV.XXXX as SPN 12-24-2017
>   14:18:46:885 : [ b9c. ba8] 0x00000000 [    TRACE_CM] [  TRACE_INFO]
>   CRpcIOManagerServer::CheckTokenForWMIServiceSID
>   (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrsrv.cpp@506):
>   CheckTokenForWMIServiceSID - IsWMIService = 0 12-24-2017 14:18:46:900
>   : [ b9c. ba8] 0x00000000 [    TRACE_CM] [  TRACE_INFO]
>   CRpcIOManagerServer::CheckTokenForComputer
>   (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrsrv.cpp@1009): **Incoming caller is not
>   in a domain** 12-24-2017 14:20:32:035 : [ b9c. d5c] 0x800706d9 [
>   TRACE_CM] [ **TRACE_ERROR**] CRpcIOManagerClient::SetRpcSecurity
>   (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrclt.cpp@547): [Remote:MRFAPPDVL
>   b8f70426] **Call to RpcEpResolveBinding failed** 12-24-2017 14:20:32:035 :
>   [ b9c. d5c] 0x80000171 [    TRACE_CM] [ TRACE_ERROR]
>   CRpcIOManagerClient::SecureBuildContextWrapper
>   (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrclt.cpp@749): [Remote:MRFAPPDVL
>   b8f70426] Call to SetRpcSecurity failed 12-24-2017 14:20:32:035 : [
>   b9c. d5c] 0x80000171 [    TRACE_CM] [ TRACE_ERROR]
>   CRpcIOManagerClient::Bind
>   (com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrclt.cpp@312): [Remote:MRFAPPDVL
>   b8f70426] SecureBuildContextWrapper call failed. **This is usually due
>   to security/network configuration issues.**